# How to find if a field exists in vbscript/asp

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I have a recordset. And I want to know if a field with name MyField exists.

How to find out if a field exists?

```
while not oRs.eof   
  if oRs.Fields("MyField").Exists = true and oRs("MyField") then 
    ' Result is true
  end if

  oRs.movenext
wend
```

Yrs Sincerly

Comment: You can also use field index if you don't know its name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need a helper function to iterate the fields and compare;

```
dim exists: exists = ContainsField(oRs, "MyField")

while not oRs.eof 
    if exists ...
```

Using

```
function ContainsField(rs, name)
    dim fld
    name = UCase$(name)
    for each fld in rs.Fields
        if UCase$(fld.name) = name then
            ContainsField = true
            Exit Function
        end if
    next

    ContainsField = False
End function
```

Comment: If you are using the helper function a lot and is bothering your performance, you could consider storing the field names as keys in a `Scripting.Dictionary` object. This creates a hashmap and the `.Exists(key)` method is really fast.